# word frequency of string counter is sometimes wrong

Tags: c, string, count

I hope you can help me I worked on this code. The code works like this

- user inputs a string for example "hey john, how are you john?
- the program erases signs like "'?' ,  ',' '!' " etc.
- the program writes a string after erasing the signs : "hey john how are you john?"
- and the code outputs the frequency of each word:

hey : 1
john: 2
how : 1
are : 1
you : 1

but my code counts sometimes wrong. For example when I type "bye bye bye hello hello hello"

the output is : 
bye : 3
hello : 1

My code does the john example right, but the bye bye... example wrong.

How do I have to change my code? Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char words[80][80];

void clear_string(char *text);
int extract_and_count(char *source,  int *count);
void clearArray(char array[]);
int indexInWords(char string[]);
void print(int countOfWords, int count[]);
int equals(char *string1, char *string2);


int main() {
    char string[80];
    int count[80];

    printf("please enter your text: ");

    scanf("%[^\n]s", string);

    clear_string(string);

    printf("%s\n", string);
    int countOfWords = extract_and_count(string, count);

    print(countOfWords, count);

    return 0;
}

void clear_string(char *text){

    int i = 0;

    for(;i < strlen(text);++i){
        if( text[i] == '.' || text[i] == ',' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?'){

            int k = i + 1;
            for(; k < strlen(text);++k){
                text[k-1] = text[k];
            }

            k = strlen(text) - 1;
            text[k] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

int extract_and_count(char *source,  int *count){

    int wordCounter = 0;
    char string[80];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    clearArray(string);

    for(; i < strlen(source);++i, ++k){

        if(source[i] != ' '){
                string[k] = source[i];
        }else{
            if(string[0] == '\0'){
                break;
            }
            int index = indexInWords(string);

            if(index == -1){

                strcpy(words[wordCounter], string);
                count[wordCounter] = 1;
                wordCounter++;
            }else{
                count[index] += 1;
            }

            clearArray(string);
            k = -1;


        }

    }

    return wordCounter;
}

void clearArray(char array[]){
    memset(array,0,strlen(array));
    //array[0] = '\0';
}

int indexInWords(char string[]){

    int i = 0;
    for(;i < 80;++i){
        if(equals(words[i], string) == 0){
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

void print(int countOfWords, int count[]){


    for(int i = 0;i < countOfWords; ++i){
        printf("%s : %d\n",words[i], count[i]);

    }






}

int equals(char string1[], char string2[]){



    return strcmp(string1, string2);
}
```

Comment: In `clear_string` you have not terminated the shortened string.

Comment: how can i do this

Comment: I think you are complicating the problem solving. Does your program have to have that *structure* or would you accept an improvement that won't have much in common with the code you wrote?

Comment: the code for said string collapsing algorithm could be *much* simpler.

Comment: The crudest way would be to change the loop end condition to `k <= strlen(text);` to copy the terminator too, also remove the subsequent space writing. But as commented, there are better ways.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what  you are saying :) can someone say me what i can change in my code so that i dont have the problem?

Comment: I don't know what else might be wrong that a simple tweak would fix. I stopped reading at the first problem I saw. Are you acquainted with *debugger* yet?

Comment: no, is it complicated to solve my problem with my code above?

Comment: oooh thank you weather vane you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The most significant problem I found was in `extract_and_count()` -- it doesn't count the last word as it only counts words followed by space.  The bandaid is to check if `string` has anything in it after the loop, and if so, process it.  Below is my rework for that fix and general style:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void clear_string(char *text);
int extract_and_count(char *source, int count[]);
void clearArray(char array[]);
int indexInWords(char string[]);
void print(int countOfWords, int count[]);
bool equals(char *string1, char *string2);

#define BUFFER_SIZE (512)
#define MAX_WORD_COUNT (80)
#define MAX_WORD_SIZE (64)

char words[MAX_WORD_COUNT][MAX_WORD_SIZE];

int main() {
    char string[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int count[MAX_WORD_COUNT];

    printf("Please enter your text: ");

    while (fgets(string, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Please (re)enter your text: ");
    }

    clear_string(string);

    int countOfWords = extract_and_count(string, count);

    print(countOfWords, count);

    return 0;
}

void clear_string(char *text) {

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        if (text[i] == '.' || text[i] == ',' || text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '?' || text[i] == '\n') {

            int length = strlen(text);

            for (int k = i + 1; k < length; k++) {
                text[k - 1] = text[k];
            }

            text[length - 1] = '\0';

            i--;
        }
    }
}

int extract_and_count(char *source, int count[]) {

    int wordCounter = 0;
    char string[MAX_WORD_SIZE] = {'\0'};

    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < strlen(source); i++, k++) {

        if (source[i] != ' ') {
            string[k] = source[i];
        } else {
            if (string[0] == '\0') {
                break;
            }
            int index = indexInWords(string);

            if (index == -1) {
                strcpy(words[wordCounter], string);
                count[wordCounter] = 1;
                wordCounter++;
            } else {
                count[index] += 1;
            }

            clearArray(string);
            k = -1;
        }
    }

    if (string[0] != '\0') {
        int index = indexInWords(string);

        if (index == -1) {
            strcpy(words[wordCounter], string);
            count[wordCounter] = 1;
            wordCounter++;
        } else {
            count[index] += 1;
        }
    }

    return wordCounter;
}

void clearArray(char array[]) {
    memset(array, 0, strlen(array));
}

int indexInWords(char string[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORD_COUNT; i++) {
        if (equals(words[i], string)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

void print(int countOfWords, int count[]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < countOfWords; i++) {
        printf("%s : %d\n", words[i], count[i]);
    }
}

bool equals(char string1[], char string2[]) {
    return strcmp(string1, string2) == 0;
}
```

The next most significant issue I see is you don't keep track of how many entries in `words[][]` are used, so `indexInWords()` could easily wander off making comparisons against uninitialized memory.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", string);` is poor code 1) It saves nothing in `string` if first character is `\n` leaving `string` uninitialized. 2) No buffer overflow prevention  3) `s`  has no use 4) Good code checks the return value of `scanf()`  OTOH - it is OP's code.

Comment: @chux, I didn't realize if I fix one or two errors in the OP's code that I then become responsible for all of them!  I've swapped `scanf()` for `fgets()` and updated `clear_string()` to clean off the resultant trailing newline.  Not perfect, but better...

Comment: hey thanks a lot, there is only one thing, how can i do that i can only give strings with the maximum lenght of 80 words?

Comment: @Sedem, I'm not sure what you're asking but I'll guess the answer is change the value of `BUFFER_SIZE ` from 512 to 80.  (If you do so, then cutting `MAX_WORD_SIZE` in half probably makes sense as well.)

Answer (score 0):

In extract_and_count you break out of the for-loop when you find 2 spaces. Also you did not check for the last word of source. Changed it to:

```
int extract_and_count(char *source,  int *count){

    int wordCounter = 0;
    char string[80];
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    clearArray(string);
    for(; i < strlen(source)+1;++i, ++k){ 

        if(source[i] != ' ' && source[i] != 0){
                string[k] = source[i];
        }else{
            if(string[0] != '\0'){
                int index = indexInWords(string);

              if(index == -1){

                  strcpy(words[wordCounter], string);
                  count[wordCounter] = 1;
                  wordCounter++;
              }else{
                  count[index] += 1;
              } }

            clearArray(string);
            k = -1;


        }

    }

    return wordCounter;
}
```